# Loading xml files through node.js on windows

Tags: xml, windows, node.js

I'm trying to load and parse a local XML file through Node.js hosted in IIS.
I used fs readFile to read the string and the [xmldom](https://github.com/jindw/xmldom)  module to parse it.
It works until file size is small (few kb), but if I try to load a 3Mb xml it fails.

Which other xml modulefor windows could perform better?

This is my code

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('C:\\Temp\\TEST.xml', 'ascii', function(err,data){
    if(err) {
        console.log("Could not open file"+ err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    var Dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
    var doc = new Dom().parseFromString(data.substring(2,data.lenght));
    console.log(doc.childNodes[0].localName);
});
```

After 5 min the xml the parser is still running, while on a simpler example it works. i saved the output from msinfo32 in xml format

After 10 mins output is RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

output is generated from "msinfo32 /nfo C:\TEMP\TEST.NFO"

Comment: 'It fails' won't do. How is it failing?  Are you sure it's a valid document?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the xml document is valid here:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

If it is and it's failing I suggest to open an issue on their github page

You can search for other modules on [npm](http://search.npmjs.org/)

I've personally used [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) without problems

Comment: xml file is valid, but it takes too long to be generated...I don't know if the failing reason is just an iis timeout, however I need something faster.

xml2json requires expat, which is not available on windows unless you compile it.

Is there a module to work with xml streams? would be faster?

Comment: IIS timeout seems unlikely, how long does it take? (I hope it won't take more than 30 seconds ;) ). Anyway, probably you're stuck with xmldom because most of the other node parsers use libxml2, and you should use it through cygwin on windows.. not a great idea.. Just make sure that is the parser itself that is failing and not other/your code and open an issue, does it throw any exception? can you spot a timeout on IIS?

Comment: this is my code var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('C:\\Temp\\TEST.xml', 'ascii', function(err,data){
if(err) {
 console.log("Could not open file"+ err);
 process.exit(1);
}
var Dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

var doc = new Dom().parseFromString(data.substring(2,data.lenght));
console.log(doc.childNodes[0].localName); 
}); after 5 min the xml the parser is still running, while on a simpler example it works. i saved the output from msinfo32 in xml format

Comment: after 10 mins output is RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: I've updated your question with those details, could be a library bug, seems like the stack limit is exhausted, so... probably an infinite loop somewhere, or you've got a really really really long list of nested elements in that document.. Not sure how to help, try to open an issue and provide a test xml document to be make the author able to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

msinfo32 outputs in "ucs2", the wrong encoding caused the issue.
Xmldom parser works fine, even if it takes a couple of minutes to parse the whole file.

I used [xml-splitter](https://github.com/lindory-project/node-xml-splitter) to extract the xml branch to be parsed

Answer (score -1):

I see that you wrote lenght and not length... Maybe that's the problem!

Comment: This should be a comment (checking it's a cut and paster error) rather than as answer as it doesn't provide a solution to OP's problem.